# MySQL - Always return exactly n records

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table with many (always at least 1, sometimes more than 6) values for any given foreign key ID. Here's a query that gets the values descending and limits the output to a maximum of 6 values:

```
SELECT Diameter
FROM  `TreeDiameters` 
WHERE TreeID = ?
ORDER BY Diameter DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 6;
```

But how can I always get exactly 6 values back (the extra ones being NULLs or blank or whatever)?

Comment: What would be the point in bringing back entirely null rows?

Comment: Because of this `LIMIT 0 , 6;`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `union all` and `limit`:

```
(SELECT Diameter
 FROM  `TreeDiameters` 
 WHERE TreeID = ?
) union all
(select NULL as Diameter
 from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
       select 5 union all select 6
      ) n 
)
ORDER BY Diameter DESC
LIMIT 0, 6;
```

MySQL puts `NULL` values last with a descending sort.  But you can also be specific:

```
ORDER BY (Diameter is not null) DESC, Diameter DESC
```